# Random object from a JSON file

Tags: node.js, fs

So I have a file called pokemon.json, it is a rather large list of pokemon and all of their stats. I am trying to read the data from the json file, generate a random number, then send the pokemon's information who's id matches the random number.

Currently I am trying this

```
var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('pokemon.json');
  var pokemon2 = JSON.parse(rawdata);

  var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (1 + 1169) - 1);

  var pokemon = pokemon2[randomNum];

  console.log(pokemon);
  console.log(typeof(pokemon));

  res.json(pokemon);
```

I've tried using for loops to loop through the data, it seems to only give me usable data about a quarter of the time. I would assume it has to do with it not having all of the data before trying to find the random one, but I am unsure of how to resolve this.

First few lines from JSON

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Bulbasaur","stage":1,"galar_dex":"foreign","base_stats":[45,49,49,65,65,45],"ev_yield":[0,0,0,1,0,0],"abilities":["Overgrow","Overgrow","Chlorophyll"],"types":["Grass","Poison"],"items":[],"exp_group":"MediumSlow","egg_groups":["Monster","Grass"],"hatch_cycles":20,"height":0.7,"weight":6.9,"color":"Green","level_up_moves":[[1,"Tackle"],[1,"Growl"],[3,"Vine Whip"],[6,"Growth"],[9,"Leech Seed"],[12,"Razor Leaf"],[15,"Poison Powder"],[15,"Sleep Powder"],[18,"Seed Bomb"],[21,"Take Down"],[24,"Sweet Scent"],[27,"Synthesis"],[30,"Worry Seed"],[33,"Double-Edge"],[36,"Solar Beam"]],"egg_moves":["Skull Bash","Petal Dance","Curse","Ingrain","Nature Power","Toxic"],"tms":[10,11,17,19,21,24,25,28,29,31,34,39,41,46,50,74,76,88,94],"trs":[0,1,17,20,22,26,27,59,65,71,72,77,85],"evolutions":[{"species":"Ivysaur-0","method":"LevelUp","method_value":16}],"description":"While it is young, it uses the nutrients that are stored in the seed on its back in order to grow."},
    {"id":2,"name":"Ivysaur","stage":2,"galar_dex":"foreign","base_stats":[60,62,63,80,80,60],"ev_yield":[0,0,0,1,1,0],"abilities":["Overgrow","Overgrow","Chlorophyll"],"types":["Grass","Poison"],"items":[],"exp_group":"MediumSlow","egg_groups":["Monster","Grass"],"hatch_cycles":20,"height":1,"weight":13,"color":"Green","level_up_moves":[[1,"Tackle"],[1,"Growl"],[1,"Vine Whip"],[1,"Growth"],[9,"Leech Seed"],[12,"Razor Leaf"],[15,"Poison Powder"],[15,"Sleep Powder"],[20,"Seed Bomb"],[25,"Take Down"],[30,"Sweet Scent"],[35,"Synthesis"],[40,"Worry Seed"],[45,"Double-Edge"],[50,"Solar Beam"]],"egg_moves":[],"tms":[10,11,17,19,21,24,25,28,29,31,34,39,41,46,50,74,76,88,94],"trs":[0,1,17,20,22,26,27,59,65,71,72,77,85],"evolutions":[{"species":"Venusaur-0","method":"LevelUp","method_value":32}],"description":"Exposure to sunlight adds to its strength. Sunlight also makes the bud on its back grow larger."},
...
....
....
....
...
{"id":1170,"name":"Eternatus 1","stage":3,"galar_dex":"400","base_stats":[255,115,250,125,250,130],"ev_yield":[3,0,0,0,0,0],"abilities":["Pressure","Pressure","Pressure"],"types":["Poison","Dragon"],"items":[],"exp_group":"Slow","egg_groups":["Undiscovered"],"hatch_cycles":120,"height":100,"weight":0,"color":"Purple","level_up_moves":[[1,"Poison Tail"],[1,"Confuse Ray"],[1,"Dragon Tail"],[1,"Agility"],[8,"Toxic"],[16,"Venoshock"],[24,"Dragon Dance"],[32,"Cross Poison"],[40,"Dragon Pulse"],[48,"Flamethrower"],[56,"Dynamax Cannon"],[64,"Cosmic Power"],[72,"Recover"],[80,"Hyper Beam"],[88,"Eternabeam"]],"egg_moves":[],"tms":[6,8,9,11,16,17,18,21,24,25,26,39,57,58,73,74,76,92,97],"trs":[2,12,20,22,26,27,33,44,51,54,57,62,70,78,91],"evolutions":[],"description":null}
]
```

To add additional clarification, I ran the code 3 times. Here are the responses that were console logged

```
undefined
[0] undefined
[0] undefined
[0] undefined
[0] {
[0]   id: 606,
[0]   name: 'Beheeyem',
[0]   stage: 2,
[0]   galar_dex: '278',
[0]   base_stats: [ 75, 75, 75, 125, 95, 40 ],
[0]   ev_yield: [ 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 ],
[0]   abilities: [ 'Telepathy', 'Synchronize', 'Analytic' ],
[0]   types: [ 'Psychic' ],
[0]   items: [],
[0]   exp_group: 'MediumFast',
[0]   egg_groups: [ 'HumanLike' ],
[0]   hatch_cycles: 20,
[0]   height: 1,
[0]   weight: 34.5,
[0]   color: 'Brown',
[0]   level_up_moves: [
[0]     [ 1, 'Psychic Terrain' ],
[0]     [ 1, 'Confusion' ],
[0]     [ 1, 'Growl' ],
[0]     [ 1, 'Imprison' ],
[0]     [ 1, 'Teleport' ],
[0]     [ 18, 'Psybeam' ],
[0]     [ 24, 'Power Split' ],
[0]     [ 24, 'Guard Split' ],
[0]     [ 30, 'Headbutt' ],
[0]     [ 36, 'Zen Headbutt' ],
[0]     [ 45, 'Recover' ],
[0]     [ 52, 'Calm Mind' ],
[0]     [ 60, 'Wonder Room' ],
[0]     [ 68, 'Psychic' ]
[0]   ],
[0]   egg_moves: [],
[0]   tms: [
[0]      8,  9, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21,
[0]     22, 23, 24, 25, 30, 31, 33, 39,
[0]     44, 48, 60, 61, 70, 71, 76, 91
[0]   ],
[0]   trs: [
[0]      8, 11, 12, 19, 20, 25, 26,
[0]     27, 33, 34, 35, 38, 40, 44,
[0]     49, 58, 65, 68, 69, 70, 82,
[0]     83
[0]   ],
[0]   evolutions: [],
[0]   description: 'Sometimes found drifting above wheat fields, this Pokémon can control the memories of its opponents.'
[0] }
[0] object
```

Comment: what is structure of pokemon.json?

Comment: array of objects

Comment: i mean add json to question so we can see what is going wrong

Comment: added the first few lines. its a pretty large file

Comment: Try to ensure that your pokemon isn't out of range by using the actual length of the array in your json to generate a random id: `Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon2.length);` (using `Math.floor` and `array.length` ensures that the id is somewhere between 0 and the arrays actual size). Also `pokemon[randomNum]` does not exist, as pokemon contains an item of the array but isn't an array itself.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A faster way to do so?

Comment: the highest id goes up to 1170. I multiplied the math.random by the largest and smallest ids to get a useable number.

Comment: Currently, when the code runs, about 75% of the time it will respond with undefined. The other 25% of the time it will respond with a pokemon

Comment: Use `array.length`, you are one pokemon away from having to update your script! And knowing the Pokemon Company, a new special exclusive pokemon could happen anytime.

Comment: I see what you mean now haha. Thank you <3

Comment: @TheTravelingCoder I think that might be due to wrong indexing make sure the length is correct or as suggested above use array.length

Comment: So adjusting to using ```var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * pokemon2.length);``` it fixed the issue.
But, why? If the randomly generated number was within the min and max of the id, why would it still result in undefined?

Comment: Are you sure the numbers were actually correct? One missed comma in your JSON can ruin your assumptions. Have you tried logging the array length? And logging the index you are selecting? Try logging all variables and then try to figuree out if your logic had a flaw, or your data... Thats development for ya :) (also the +1, then -1 is kind of weird and unnecessary? Thats why you can skip that altogether with `Math.floor`)

Comment: (Also `pokemon.id` might be `1170`, but officially there are `896` pokemon, so any number betweem `896` and `1170` would not necessarily exist in your array! The length of your array probably doesn't match the id, but its hard to see at a glance in a json that large!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix how you pick random pokemon

```
   var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (1 + 1169) - 1);

-> var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon2.length);
```

Comment: Great explanation of what is going on, I get the impression you copied this from the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here

```
var pokemon = pokemon2[randomNum];

console.log(pokemon);
console.log(pokemon[randomNum]);

res.json(pokemon);
```

You are trying to console.log pokemon[randomNum] while your array is pokemon2

Comment: Although he also logs `pokemon`, which is assume would be valid, whereas `pokemon[randomNum]` is just `undefined`.

Comment: This is incorrect. I removed that line of code and makes zero difference. Worst case scenario that would cause it to console log undefined

Comment: @TheTravelingCoder I am just pointing out what the issue is; pokemon is the value you want to use not pokemon[randomNum]